# How is $-2^n + 2^{(n-1)} = -2^{(n-1)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can somebody help me to see how $-2^n + 2^{(n-1)} = -2^{n-1}$

I know if I had to add $ 2^{(n-1)} + 2^{(n-1)} = 2* 2^{(n-1)} = 2^n$

But I can't see how it is done in the first line. Can somebody help
me?

Comment: Factor out $2^{n-1}$ and you’re left with $-2+1$ in parentheses.

Comment: Substract $2^{n-1}+2^n$ on both sides of $2^{n-1}+2^{n-1} = 2^n$.

Comment: So you know that $a+a=2a\,$, then just rewrite it as $-2a + a = -a\,$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can somebody help me to see how $-2^n + 2^{(n-1)} = -2^{n-1}$
>
> I know if I had to add $ 2^{(n-1)} + 2^{(n-1)} = 2* 2^{(n-1)} = 2^n$
>
> But I can't see how it is done in the first line. Can somebody help
> me?

$$$$
So you figured out that

$$2^{n-1} + 2^{n-1} = 2^n.$$

But you don't know how to rearrange this to:

$$-2^n + 2^{n-1} = -2^{n-1}$$ ?

It's simply a rearrangement of the equation....